# Javascript templates (eg.Underscore / Lodash): informative advice

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, template-engine, lodash

I'm currently learning about Javascript templates and I have an informative question.

What is the benefit of populating a javascript template with json data from the server, opposed to gathering the html string at the server (eg. PHP) and returning it with a jQuery Ajax call?

As this templating is performed with Javascript at the client side, wouldn't creating the template on the server be a lot faster (the server is more powerful than the client)?

What is the actual benefit of doing this client side?
I bumped into this as I'm currently learning how to develop an SPA with Backbone, which I would like to use together with Marionette and require.

Thanks.

Comment: It is the difference between `<p>I want 11 pancakes.</p>` and the number `11`. One is an opaque string that you can't do anything with except toss it on the page, the other is a piece of meaningful data that you can manipulate or put it on the page using a `<p>I want <%= n %> pancakes.</p>` template or put somewhere else with a `<td>Pancakes:</td><td><%= n %></td>` template.

Comment: Makes sense. So it comes down to the fact that information is downloaded from the server in a form that you can manipulate (ie. json); I wonder then if I should assess for each situation independently whether using a template is useful in certain circumstances; In case of downloading a list of non-reusable information, would a server-created template be more performant? I mean, fetching straight html from the server and pusing it into a div container.

Comment: Generally you end up going all-in one way or the other. Today's opaque hunk of HTML is tomorrow morning's critical piece of data.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up for me. It's true that json will allow me to dynamically manipulate my data on the client at any time in the future, rather than needing to change my server scripts all the time. I will follow the convention as most bb developers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the server is more powerful than client. Yes, but if you have 1000 clients that request the page? It becomes hard for the server and you try to use server-side caching, load balancing and so on. So the client side template rendering allows each client to care about itself. It offloads the server incredibly. For example you can provide HTML templates and JavaScript code once and the browser will cache it. So the server doesn't even send this stuff on every next request from current client and only ensures the actual data providing and manipulating with it e.g. via REST architecture. In this way you mostly transfer the data only.
Backbone and other client-side frameworks allows you to offload the server. It works always faster when each client renders the page or the part of page for itself.
Just compare a response in these two cases for "GET Users" request:

**JSON** response (REST) **for the client side rendering**:

```
[
    {"name": "Jimmy", "email": "jimmy@gmail.com"},
    {"name:" "Billy", "email": "billy@gmail.com"}
]
```

**HTML** response (traditional) **rendered by the server**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Jimmy
        </td>
        <td>
            jimmy@gmail.com
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Billy
        </td>
        <td>
            billy@gmail.com
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously if you have 100 users to render you'll have a much more HTML to render on the server side and transfer via HTTP (CPU, RAM, Bandwidth).

But in case of client-side rendering you just need a template of table and a template of one (!) table row (for particular example) to render users in loop.

So the server only cares about the data, authentication and authorization.
The application is distributed. You offload your server and allow the browser to do all the non-sensitive work. Each client cares about itself.

Comment: That sounds very logical and true. I'm currently trying out backbone, and I honestly have to say that it takes me quite some time to get used to it. The examples are one thing, but I don't find it that easy to really do the things that you need without someone more experienced to guide you in the right direction sometimes.

Comment: The best way is to try to work on some existing code base, e.g. something from open source and figure out how things work together. But I bet in 30 days you'll see it's easy and fun.

Comment: Can't wait to get to that point. Thanks for your advice on the matter!